# Installing python package from github

Tags: python-3.x

How to install this package from git hub, please?

https://github.com/oimodeler/oimodeler/tree/main/docs

I assume that somehow through docs directory.

Edit after advice:

When I ran

```
bash-5.1$ pwd
.../oimodeler-main
bash-5.1$ ls
docs  examples  images  LICENSE  oimodeler  README.md  setup.py
bash-5.1$ python setup.py install


.../.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    .../.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.9'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

The next try:

```
bash-5.1$ python setup.py install --user,
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --user, not recognized
bash-5.1$ python setup.py install --user
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
```

I am using Feroda 34.

Comment: cd to the main directory and do `python setup.py install` https://github.com/oimodeler/oimodeler

Comment: if you run `python setup.py install` from the docs sub-directory it won't because the `setup.py` file isn't there. 
You should execute that command one directory above the docs directory, which should the project's root.

Comment: I ran that in /oimodeler-main - the folder with setup.py and the one above docs.

Comment: use python setup.py install --user, so it will install to your local folder instead the global one.

Comment: It also did not succeeded (I edited my question).

Comment: It was installed somehow - it is not complaining about package. I tried to run some the examples and obtained an error: `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'` I did not find asscalar in any scripts in oimodeler directory.